# How to detect it was duplicate entry on VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, duplicates

I have a problem on making avoid or detect duplicate data entry in VB.NET using SQL Server, and also pop up message when there is duplicate entry.

This is my add button code:

```vb
Dim sql = "INSERT INTO studentAttendence(studentID, date, time, subject, attendence) " &
    "VALUES(@studentID, @date, @time, @subject, @attendence)" &
    "WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM studentAttendence WHERE studentID = @studentID)"

Using cn As New SqlConnection("My sql Connection string")
    Dim commands As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

    commands.Parameters.Add("@studentID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
    commands.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DateTimePicker1.Text
    commands.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DateTimePicker2.Text
    commands.Parameters.Add("@subject", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ComboBox1.Text
    commands.Parameters.Add("@attendence", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ComboBox2.Text

    commands.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Or is there any other methods for making avoid duplicate entries. I just want to avoid same date and subject of a student to add. So I can only add subject on the next date if I already add subject on today's date of studentID.

Comment: You're not defining what constitutes a duplicate nor are you making any effort to get the duplicate data. Could you provide clarification?

Comment: @David i want to prevent from adding duplicate data. for example today's date i have add a subject on  a student id. So i must avoid to add same subject on today's date on a studentid but i can add different subject on today's date of a studentid

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Could you clearly define what defines a duplicate? Is it just that the date, student id, and subject cannot match an existing record or are there more requirements?

Comment: @David its just date,subject and studentid only that cannot match an existing record.

Comment: Why are you storing a date as an NVarChar? Dates should be stored as dates.

Comment: It would be a good idea to open the connection before executing your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use If Not Exists before the insert. This method only requires a single hit on the database. Add a comman at the end of the first line of the Using block, then delete Dim before commands. This will include commands in the Using block.

```
Private Function InsertAttendance() As Integer
    Dim sql = "If Not Exists (Select 1 From studentAttendence 
Where studnetID = @studentID And date = @date And subject = @subject)
INSERT INTO studentAttendence(studentID, date, time, subject, attendence) 
VALUES(@studentID, @date, @time, @subject, @attendence);"
    Dim NumRowsAffected As Integer
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("My sql Connection string"),
           commands As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
        commands.Parameters.Add("@studentID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        commands.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DateTimePicker1.Text
        commands.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DateTimePicker2.Text
        commands.Parameters.Add("@subject", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        commands.Parameters.Add("@attendence", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ComboBox2.Text
        cn.Open()
        NumRowsAffected = commands.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    Return NumRowsAffected
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        If InsertAttendance() = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Success")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Entry")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show($"Error Entering Attendance {ex.Message}")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Be sure to check the datatypes of your parameters with the database.

Comment: I got a error message that says incorrect syntax near the keyword "WHERE". The data types all are perfectly changed.

Comment: So sorry. I forgot to get rid of the not exists in the where clause. See the corrected `Dim sql` string.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm glad to learn new way for the duplicate entry, its helped so much and the problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function that queries your data table to return the row count where the Date, Subject, and StudentId match what you're wanting to insert. If the returned result is greater than 0 then display the message.

Here is a function that returns -1 if something went wrong or the row count:

```vb
Private Function GetRowCount(ByVal studentIdParameter As String, ByVal dateParameter As DateTime, ByVal subjectParameter As String) As Integer
    'Declare the object to return
    Dim count As Integer = -1

    'Declare the connection object
    Dim con As OleDbConnection

    'Wrap code in Try/Catch
    Try
        'Set the connection object to a new instance
        'TODO: Change "My Connection String Here" with a valid connection string
        con = New OleDbConnection("My Connection String Here")

        'Create a new instance of the command object
        'TODO: Change [ID] to a valid column
        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT Count([ID]) FROM [MyTable] WHERE studentID=@studentId, AND date=@date AND subject=@subject", con)
            'Parameterize the query
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentId", OleDbType.NVarChar).Value = studentIdParameter
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = dateParameter.Date
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@subject", OleDbType.NVarChar).Value = subjectParameter

            'Open the connection
            con.Open()

            'Use ExecuteScalar to return a single value
            count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

            'Close the connection
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Display the error
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        'Check if the connection object was initialized
        If con IsNot Nothing Then
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                'Close the connection if it was left open(exception thrown)
                con.Close()
            End If

            'Dispose of the connection object
            con.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try

    'Return the row count
    Return count
End Function
```

To implement it, you'd do something like:

```vb
Dim rowCount = GetRowCount(TextBox1.Text, DateTimePicker1.Value, ComboBox1.Text)
If (rowCount = -1) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong checking for duplicates")
ElseIf (rowCount = 0) Then
    ' Insert record
Else
    MessageBox.Show("A record already exists with this studentId, date, and subject.")
End If
```

Comment: its just keep on telling something went wrong checking for duplicates, and 
 I can't enter any new value also.

Comment: If you add your connection to the Using block you can get rid of the Finally.

Comment: There is no need to check connection.State before closing a connection. From MS docs "An application can call Close more than one time. No exception is generated." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: The OP seems to be using Sql Server. It could confuse the OP to see the OleDb code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I thought you were using OleDb. You'll just need to change it to use the appropriate class. But right now I just have the exception printing to the Console, so either check the exception message there or change it to use a MessageBox.

Comment: i can add attendence, but its doesn't detect the duplicate.